# how to fetch the data from server like given in console in reactjs using axios

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, frontend

I have written backend code for my project. In console I am getting all data but the problem in fetching those marked data in given pic [image: consle.png]

I tried to fetch the data as given in below code. My question is this correct method to fetch data or am doing in wrong way if I am doing wrong way then what is the correct method
below is my code

```
class Example extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          data: [],
          loading: false,
          error: null,
        };
      }
    
      componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ loding: true });
        const token = getTokenu();
        Axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/article/', {
          headers: {
            Authorization: "Token " + token,
          },
        })
          .then((res) => {
            console.log(res.data);
            this.setState({ data: res.data, loding: false });
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            this.setState({ error: error, loading: false });
          });
      }
    
      render() {
        const { data, error, loading } = this.state;
        return (
          <div className="mt-4">
                    {loading && <ClipLoader size={30} color={"#f3990f"} />}
            <Carousel
              infiniteLoop={true}
              showThumbs={false}
              showIndicators={false}
              autoPlay={true}
              >
                {data.map((item) => {
                  return (
                    <div key={item.id}>
                      <img className="articleposter" src={item.articledetail_set.poster} alt="tag" />
                      <p>{item.articledetail_set[index].date}</p>
                      <p>{item.articledetail_set[index].minutes}</p>
                      <p>{item.articledetail_set[index].seconds}</p>
                    </div>
                  )
                } )}
            </Carousel>
          </div>
        );
      }
}

export default Example
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result.data` from axios contains the whole response.

you probably wanteed to se the results from data into state

try this

```
this.setState({ data: res.data.results, loding: false });
```